# Hardware Printer, Mouse

Tags: settings, mouse, printer

everyone in the elementary Os world,
I must say Having come from an Apple background I am liking what I see so far. I am running elementary OS 5.0 Juno 64 bit

Question 1 
I notice there is no Minimise / maximise buttons on applications, I have to right click.  Can this be overcome? Are there shortcut keyboard strokes for it perhaps??

Question 2 
I have a HP desk jet printer 2600 series and I Can NOT get it to work wireless.  It connects to my WiFi but in doing so kicks me out

Question 3
My mouse scrolls the wrong way, IE when I scroll the wheel towards me the text goes up,not down.  I am unable to find any settings that relate to that

Hope someone can help me out

TIA
Ozzyrod

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: The minimise / maximise button is on the right (by default)

[image: minimise-maximise]

If you have elementary tweaks installed you can customize the layout style.

[image]

Example OSX:

[image]

Windows:

[image]

Question 3: System settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Mouse -> Natural scrolling

I am afraid I can not help you with question 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I do understand that the min/max is on right.  My issue is that you have to right click to access it.  On other systems I have had there is a squatre block and an underline.  They are used to maximise and minimise.  No big deal, I just wondered if that was available with some tweaking

Comment: in relation to elementary tweaks I used terminal and cant find?  So I take it that means it is not in repository?   Do I download from web?

Comment: Q2.  I have installed a universal printer to usb cable and will just stick with that I think.  Save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the minimize/maximize it is the double arrow icon on the right top.

What I think you want is for the window to minimize all the way to the the dock not just resize to a smaller window. For that you do have to either right click or click on the apps icon in the dock.

Answer (score 0):

To install elementary tweaks follow the following
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

Tweaks will be installed into the system setting folder